# CakePHP Contact Form

Tags: php, cakephp

I have built a contact form using CakePHP on my site. The controller logic is as follows:

```
<?php

class ContactController extends AppController
{
    var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');

    var $components = array ('Email','RequestHandler');

    var $name = 'Contact';

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Auth->allow(array('*'));  
    }

    function index()
    {
        if ($this->RequestHandler->isPost())
        {
            $this->Contact->set($this->data);
            if ($this->Contact->validates())
            {
                $this->Email->to = '###';  
                $this->Email->subject = 'Contact message from ' . $this->data['Contact']['name'];  
                $this->Email->from = $this->data['Contact']['email'];  

                $this->Email->send($this->data['Contact']['message']);

                $this->render('success');
            }
        }
    }

}

?>
```

What I want to do is when a user submits the form is show another view file such as `success.ctp` but what happens is even though they have a new view they could refresh the page and send the data again and again. How do I stop this...

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after you process their form data, redirect them to the same contact page (to avoid the refresh problem)

If you're not aware, you can setFlash to show a success message. But if you want to customize it the way you want, you can write a variable to Session to signal the view.

> ```
> function index()
> {
>     if ($this->RequestHandler->isPost())
>     {
>         $this->Contact->set($this->data);
>         if ($this->Contact->validates())
>         {
>             $this->Email->to = '###';  
>             $this->Email->subject = 'Contact message from ' . $this->data['Contact']['name'];  
>             $this->Email->from = $this->data['Contact']['email'];  
>             $this->Email->send($this->data['Contact']['message']);
>             $this->Session->write('Contact.postmessage', true);
>             $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
>         }
>     }
>     $this->Session->delete('Contact.postmessage');
> }
> ```

And in the view:

> ```
> if($this->Session->check('Contact.postmessage'){
>    // write out content of success.ctp
>   }else{
>    // write out form
>   }
> ```

Comment: Hi I'd prefer to show the user an alternate view on the same page instead of redirecting them. But I'm not sure how to prevent the user from sending the data again if they refreshed? Cheers

Comment: alternative view? so you might want to use $this->render('alternative_view');? About the refresh thing, it's related to how you do the first one. So fix how you want to show the alternate view first, then I'll answer the second one, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes I have done the render so now I get a message saying thanks for your email (see OP code) But if the user does the refresh it will resend the data! I'm not sure AT ALL how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: hm.. if you render another view, it's unlikely the refresh would be a problem, unless you include the same form in success.ctp. If that the case, just  set $this->data = array(); right before $this->render('success');

Comment: The form isn't on the page anymore as it's an entirely new view. The reason it sends the data again is because it's stored in the session or somewhere else and it uses the same controller action. and adding `$this->data = array();` still sends the data if the user refreshes the page.

Comment: it's not stored anywhere else. In browsers like FF, if you F5 a page that you just did a POST, FF will ask you whether you want to send the POST again, did you click yes? That's why it's probably better to direct them to another action. You don't really have to do much more, just include an empty success()method. On a side note, I just read your code again and notice you don't check if $this->data is empty or not before processing it.

Comment: I check if it is validated which is checking if it's empty or not. Plus I have seen on many websites that they send the user back to the same page e.g. `domain.com/contact` and it doesn't have the issue with the popup asking yes or no...

Answer (score 0):

You could try an approach of finding the count with the posted email less than five minutes ago or pop a Session flash message like 'Sorry you can only post every x minutes'

```
$this->Contact->find('count',array(
                               'conditions'=>array(
                                       'email'=>$this->data['Contact'] ['email'],
                                        'created <'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-5 minutes)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid sending message more then one time - place session value and check which view to render according to if that session value is placed.
e.g. on your email sending code add `$this->Session->write('sent',1);`
and when rendering: `if ($this->Session->check('sent')) $this->render('common_view'); else $this->render('alternate_view');`
And please make sure that page is redirected after email sending to itself via `$this->redirect()`.